# How to open "Devices and Printers" Control Panel in Windows 8 via CLI or AHK?

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey

I would like to automate connecting PC to phone's internet connection via Bluetooth using the AutoHotKey script which will perform the following actions:

[image: Bluetooth internet connecting UI sequence]

Once the **Devices and Printers** window is open, I should be safely able to finish most of actions by sending keystrokes.

**Now the question:**

In Windows 7,  **Devices and Printers** can be open via command line

```
control bthprops.cpl
```

but in Windows 8 the same command opens Modern UI screen **PC Settings > Devices** instead of the above window. Is there a way to open the above window programatically either via command line or via DLL call?

Comment: Thanks for the first interesting question in a while. What happens if you call `rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL bthprops.cpl,,1`? You can also set `2,3,...` instead of `1`, or even completely omit `,,1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, after some further research, I have found working command:

```
control printers
```

It opens window **Devices and Printers**, containing not only Bluetooth devices, but all known devices. So content of the window is superset of content requested in the question, but the only difference is that filtering of Bluetooth devices is not applied this time. Typing name of the device moves selection focus to its item and nothing stands in way of running command from context menu of the device. The complete script for sample device `MyPhone1` therefore is:

```
Run, control printers
WinWaitActive, Devices and Printers
Sleep, 500
Send MyPhone1{AppsKey}ca
```

And the AutoHotKey rules again. :)

**Edit:**  Upon MCL's comment, ugly waiting loop was replaced by sleek `WinWaitActive`. Thanks!

---

EDIT:

from command line:

- devices and printers:

  ```
  explorer shell:::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}
  ```
- bluetooth devices:

  ```
  explorer shell:::{28803F59-3A75-4058-995F-4EE5503B023C}
  ```
- other locations:

  [▶ list at eightforums.com](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Great that it works for you; navigating through an explorer window is naturally always an option. Btw, you don't need an ugly custom built waiting routine, just use `WinWaitActive, Devices and Printers ahk_class CabinetWClass`.

Comment: @MCL Thank you, your suggestion and name are now part of the answer.